# Flycheck not doing on-the-fly checking in Emacs anymore

Tags: emacs

I use Flycheck in Emacs24, and so far, I haven't had any problems with it. However, recently, it decided to stop doing 'on-the-fly' checking of my files, and no longer shows warnings as I type and/or save. Is there a particular thing I have to enable to make it do that, and if so, what?

I installed Flycheck via `package-install`, and have only changed one setting (the Flycheck variable that determines what C standard is used for warnings).

Comment: What happens when you press `C-c ! C-c` in a buffer with Flycheck Mode enabled?

Comment: @lunaryorn: That showed me I had something invalid on the include path - having removed it, everything works again. Thanks!